# Need help reversing the values somehow

Tags: processing

I have a very strange problem. Everything in my code works super fine, but I still have an issue.

```
import processing.serial.*;

float r_height;
float r_width;
float hypotnuse;
int d = 20;
float x ;
float y ;
float ledGlow;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

void setup () {

  size (510, 510);
  String portName = Serial.list()[8];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  background (0);
  fill(204);

  ellipseMode (CORNER);
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  ellipse (x, y, d, d);
}

void draw () {

  r_height = mouseY - y;
  r_width =  mouseX - x;
  println ("Height is " + r_height);
  println ("Width is " + r_width);
  hypotnuse = sqrt (( (sq(r_height)) + (sq (r_width)) ) );
  ledGlow = round (hypotnuse/2.84);
  myPort.write(ledGlow);

  println (ledGlow);


  }
```

I need to get values 0-255 from the hypotenuse of my triangle. but when I am writing it to the serial port `(myPort.write (ledGlow))`, i need those values to be flipped. So if the hypotenuse is 0, it actually needs to equal to 255, if it's 1 it needs to be 254 and so on. I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: If from 0-255, don't you mean 0 should switch with 255 and 1 with 254?

Comment: oh my apologies! yes that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just subtract the hypotenuse from 255 at that time, to get the flipped hypotenuse value?

```
new_hypotenuse = 255 - hypotenuse ;
```

Comment: How can i forget about such a basic trick sigh!!!! i will accept the answer right away.

Comment: it's ok, we all need a little help sometimes :)

Comment: @JoeT A more general solution is the [map](http://processing.org/reference/map_.html) function. :)

Comment: Thank you both for an awesome answer!